# Flutter app is not working in debug mode on my Vivo Phone

Tags: flutter, adb, vscode-debugger, flutter-hotreload, flutter-hotrestart

I have been working with flutter for last 2 year. But I cannot resolve this problem with my new phone Vivo V27s (android 13). Whenever I'm trying to build my app, It shows:
`Launching lib\main.dart on V2322 in debug mode...`

after taking a lot of time, it finally build the app but with error, saying:

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter (20661): The Dart VM service is listening on ************************************
```

The app stucks with black screen.

I have tried to run my app with terminal using:
`flutter run`, It works but hot-load and hot-restart do not work.

Also , it run when I discard the app and rerun it from my phone. But the hot reload and hot restart do not work. Output:

```
I/flutter (21388): The Dart VM service is listening on ************************************
```

Here is my `Flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3803], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys issue has been solved.

You can just visit vivo devoloper and tell them to authorize the `one-click authorization`, also add why you want to enable this.

Visit: https://developer.vivo.com/contact/customer-service

Tell them you want to enable `one click authorization`. They will ask you to provide device imie. You need to have your phone IMIE and send to them once they asked and it would take about 3-5 business days to be authorized. Once they tell you that they unlocked that for you ,you simple dial: `*#*#112#*#*` and find the one-click authorization. Browse some options you will find that.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your app using adb

```
adb uninstall `your app package name`
```

Comment: I can't find the package name, can you provide the path?

Comment: You can find your app package name in `android/app/build.gradle` -> `applicationId "your app package name goes here"`

Comment: not working. is there any other option to do it?