# Can we run and debug flutter projects in VIVO mobiles?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue to be addressed, which is when i try to start run and debug in my VIVO phone it is not responding eventhough i have done all my developer settings correctly and in the console of the android studio i can see only the following messsage

```
Launching lib\main.dart on V2225 in debug mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter (14113): The Dart VM service is listening on ************************************
```

I tried resetting my device settings and updated the software version to its date,
even though it is not working for me.

Comment: list device model. any errors if present

Answer (score 0):

can you try this method? [Vivo ph issue answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050433/12156289)

copied:

> You can just visit vivo devoloper and tell them to authorize the one-click authorization, also add why you want to enable this.
>
> Visit: https://developer.vivo.com/contact/customer-service
>
> Tell them you want to enable one click authorization. They will ask
> you to provide device imie. You need to have your phone IMIE and send
> to them once they asked and it would take about 3-5 business days to
> be authorized. Once they tell you that they unlocked that for you ,you
> simple dial: *#*#112#*#* and find the one-click authorization. Browse
> some options you will find that.